# Two functions from the same library: why does one generate undefined reference while the other doesn't?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, linker

I want to replace pthread_mutex_lock by pthread_mutex_trylock in a function and when I do so, I get the "undefined reference" error message (See below). If I replace the lines 411-13 by pthread_mutex_lock(&cmd_queue_lock), I don't get the linker error.

They are both from the same library which I already include. Why does one generate the linker error and the other doesn't? More importantly, how can I fix it? I tried adding "extern int pthread_mutex_trylock" and changing the order of the .o files in Makefile but both don't work.

```
$ nl clientmain.c

    12  #include <stdio.h>
    ...
    21  #include <pthread.h>

    411 if (pthread_mutex_trylock(&cmd_queue_lock) == EBUSY) {
    412     continue;
    413 }

$ make
clientmain.o: In function `createHC':
clientmain.c:411: undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_trylock'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [clientmain] Error 1
```

Comment: Show the actual linker command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admittedly I can't find any reference to a manual page telling this, but adding `-lpthread` to your final linking phase will probably do the job. I found it by looking for the symbol `pthread_mutex_trylock` in all `/usr/lib/lib*.a` files and `/usr/lib/libpthread.a` was the only one defining the symbol. Reverse engineering.

The manual page of `gcc` does say that you can/should use the `-pthread` option to `gcc` to include POSIX thread support, so that is probably the royal route. This option worked on my system too. Interestingly the regular `/usr/lib/libc.a` does offer the `pthread_mutex_lock` but not the `pthread_mutex_trylock` so that caused your confusion. Note that the manual page of `gcc` is also saying that this option has effect on preprocessing, so it may be more and better than just linking against `/usr/lib/libpthread.a`.