# Correctly including (POSIX) libraries in deeply nested source / makefiles

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile, include

Long story short: We have a large SDK containing ~1Gb of hairy code hacked together by Elbonian Code Slaves, duck-taped together by a quivering lattice of RPC's, shared memory, mutex/semaphores, and spit. It's compiled on a Linux machine for an embedded SoC target.

As part of a stab at improving part of the code, I want to add POSIX Semaphores to one of the sources, which gets included by a few RPC routines.

However, just writing some valid code & sticking

```
#include <semaphore.h>
```

at the top is of course insufficient to enable compilation.

What is required are special flags in the makefile, depending on what you read it could be any/all of:

```
-pthread
-lpthread
-lpthreads
-lrt
-rt
```

I do not have a great deal of experience writing makefiles, and unfortunately due to the size of the codebase there are multiple nested levels of them (upwards of 2,000 makefiles in the SDK) with all sorts of dependencies, all spawning from the *One True Makefile* in the root folder.

There is a lot of macroification(TM) going on in the makefiles which is not helping my efforts to unravel the correct incantation.

As a glimpse of the structure of the project and the file I'm trying to modify, the folder structure is something like:

```
/home/project/kernel/... Contains the Linux kernel & PSP / BSP
/home/project/the_system/... Contains the software suite we're building
```

And the file we're looking at is in:

```
/home/project/the_system/core_app/interface/src/messaging.c
```

Which itself is included by maybe 5 other sources, like:

```
/home/project/the_system/core_app/interface/src/sys-control.c
/home/project/the_system/core_app/interface/src/file-control.c
/home/project/the_system/core_app/interface/src/audio-control.c
```

... you get the idea. Each of these may then be included/called by other processes wishing to communicate with each other Did I mention it's all horrible?

There are makefiles in pretty much every folder up that chain, the makefile in the local folder

```
/home/project/the_system/core_app/interface/src/Makefile
```

is something like this (I removed a few bits for clarity, ignore unreferenced objects):

```
    INCLUDES += -I./ -I$(PUBLIC_INCLUDE_DIR) -I$(LINUXKERNEL_INSTALL_DIR)/include -I$(CMEM_INSTALL_DIR)/packages/ti/sdo/linuxutils/cmem/include -lpthreads

    C_FLAGS += -Wall -g -O3
    AR_FLAGS += -r

    CC = $(MVTOOL_PREFIX)gcc $(INCLUDES) $(C_FLAGS) -c
    AR = $(MVTOOL_PREFIX)ar

    REL_EXE1 = reboot_me

    REL_LIB1 = file-control.a

    REL_LIB3 = share_mem.a

    REL_LIB4 = sys-control.a

    REL_LIB5 = msg_util.a

    REL_LIB9 = messaging.a

    REL_LIB10 = sysctrl.a

    REL_LIB11 = audio-control.a

    REL_OBJ1 = file-control.o share_mem.o msg_util.o

    REL_OBJ3 = share_mem.o

    REL_OBJ4 = sys-control.o share_mem.o msg_util.o

    REL_OBJ5 = msg_util.o

    REL_OBJ9 = messaging.o

    REL_OBJ10 = sysctrl.o sys-control.o share_mem.o msg_util.o messaging.o audio-control.o

    REL_OBJ11 = audio-control.o messaging.o share_mem.o msg_util.o


    all:  $(REL_EXE1) $(REL_LIB9) $(REL_LIB12) $(REL_LIB3) $(REL_LIB1) $(REL_LIB2) $(REL_LIB4) $(REL_LIB5) $(REL_LIB6) $(REL_LIB7) $(REL_LIB8) $(REL_LIB10) $(REL_LIB11) install

    $(REL_LIB1): $(REL_OBJ1)
        $(AR) $(AR_FLAGS) $(REL_LIB1) $(REL_OBJ1)

    $(REL_LIB2): $(REL_OBJ2)
        $(AR) $(AR_FLAGS) $(REL_LIB2) $(REL_OBJ2)

    $(REL_LIB3): $(REL_OBJ3)
        $(AR) $(AR_FLAGS) $(REL_LIB3) $(REL_OBJ3)

    $(REL_LIB4): $(REL_OBJ4)
        $(AR) $(AR_FLAGS) $(REL_LIB4) $(REL_OBJ4)

    $(REL_LIB5): $(REL_OBJ5)
        $(AR) $(AR_FLAGS) $(REL_LIB5) $(REL_OBJ5)

    $(REL_LIB7): $(REL_OBJ7) 
        $(AR) $(AR_FLAGS) $(REL_LIB7) $(REL_OBJ7)

    $(REL_LIB8): $(REL_OBJ8) 
        $(AR) $(AR_FLAGS) $(REL_LIB8) $(REL_OBJ8)

    $(REL_LIB9): $(REL_OBJ9) 
        $(AR) $(AR_FLAGS) $(REL_LIB9) $(REL_OBJ9)

    $(REL_LIB10): $(REL_OBJ10) 
        $(AR) $(AR_FLAGS) $(REL_LIB10) $(REL_OBJ10)

    $(REL_LIB11): $(REL_OBJ11) 
        $(AR) $(AR_FLAGS) $(REL_LIB11) $(REL_OBJ11)

    $(REL_LIB12): $(REL_OBJ12) 
        $(AR) $(AR_FLAGS) $(REL_LIB12) $(REL_OBJ12)


    file-control.o : file-control.c $(PUBLIC_INCLUDE_DIR)/file-control.h $(PUBLIC_INCLUDE_DIR)/Msg_Def.h\
            $(PUBLIC_INCLUDE_DIR)/sys_env_type.h
        $(CC) $(C_FLAGS) -o $@ $<

    audio-control.o : audio-control.c $(PUBLIC_INCLUDE_DIR)/audio-control.h \
            $(PUBLIC_INCLUDE_DIR)/Msg_Def.h $(PUBLIC_INCLUDE_DIR)/sys_env_type.h
        $(CC) $(C_FLAGS) -o $@ $<

    share_mem.o: share_mem.c $(PUBLIC_INCLUDE_DIR)/share_mem.h
        $(CC) $(C_FLAGS) -o $@ $<

    sys-control.o : sys-control.c $(PUBLIC_INCLUDE_DIR)/sys-control.h $(PUBLIC_INCLUDE_DIR)/Msg_Def.h\
            $(PUBLIC_INCLUDE_DIR)/sys_env_type.h $(PUBLIC_INCLUDE_DIR)/share_mem.h
        $(CC) $(C_FLAGS) -o $@ $<

    msg_util.o: msg_util.c $(PUBLIC_INCLUDE_DIR)/Msg_Def.h
        $(CC) $(C_FLAGS) -o $@ $<

    messaging.o: messaging.c $(PUBLIC_INCLUDE_DIR)/messaging.h
        $(CC) $(C_FLAGS) -o $@ $<

    sysctrl.o: sysctrl.c $(PUBLIC_INCLUDE_DIR)/sysctrl.h $(PUBLIC_INCLUDE_DIR)/sys_env_type.h
        $(CC) $(C_FLAGS) -o $@ $<

    reboot_me: 
        $(MVTOOL_PREFIX)gcc -g -Wall -static  -c -o reboot_me.o reboot_me.c
        $(MVTOOL_PREFIX)gcc -o reboot_me reboot_me.o    

    clean:
        -$(RM) -f *.o
        -$(RM) -f *.a
        -$(RM) -f $(REL_EXE1)
        -$(RM) -Rf $(APP_LIB_DIR)

    install: $(REL_EXE1) $(REL_LIB3) $(REL_LIB1) $(REL_LIB2) $(REL_LIB4) $(REL_LIB5) $(REL_LIB7)
        install -d $(APP_LIB_DIR)
        install $(REL_LIB1) $(APP_LIB_DIR)
        install $(REL_LIB2) $(APP_LIB_DIR)
        install $(REL_LIB3) $(APP_LIB_DIR)
        install $(REL_LIB4) $(APP_LIB_DIR)
        install $(REL_LIB5) $(APP_LIB_DIR)
        install $(REL_LIB7) $(APP_LIB_DIR)
        install $(REL_LIB8) $(APP_LIB_DIR)
        install $(REL_LIB9) $(APP_LIB_DIR)
        install $(REL_LIB10) $(APP_LIB_DIR)
        install $(REL_LIB11) $(APP_LIB_DIR)
        install $(REL_LIB12) $(APP_LIB_DIR)
        install $(REL_EXE1) $(EXEC_DIR)
```

---

**Anyway**, having added

```
#include <semaphore.h>
```

to the top of

```
/home/project/the_system/core_app/interface/src/messaging.c
```

**what do I need to do to allow this to compile properly?**

---

As a bonus question, is there any way to determine which one of:

```
-pthread
-lpthread
-lpthreads
-lrt
-rt
```

Is the correct one for our particular build environment?

---

**Edit to add (also TL;DR):**

I seem to be encountering an exact duplicate of the scenario mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775944/two-functions-from-the-same-library-why-does-one-generate-undefined-reference-w).

However, no matter where I stick the *-lpthread* and *-lrt* arguments I get errors.

For example, I tried to add a call to pthread_mutex_trylock, and it fails to compile:

```
undefined reference to 'pthread_mutex_trylock'
```

...even though *existing* functions calling pthread_mutex_lock compile OK.

Comment: "Which itself is included ..." Wait, what? A .c file is being included?

Comment: The `-pthread` flag usually implies linking with the `pthread` library. There is, as far as I know, no `-rt` flag, but there is a `rt` library that can be linked with. If you need to link with the `rt` library (or `pthread` library for that matter) should be in the manual pages for the functions you use. If you're uncertain about a function and what libraries you need to link with (or header files to include) ***always*** consult the functions manual page.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - No, ../inc/messaging.h is being included, doubtless messaging.o /.a gets a mention in the relevant makefiles too. I was just trying to use broad strokes rather than total detail.

Comment: +1 for first paragraph, obviously.  Now I'll look at the actual problem:)

Comment: I'd find a really high bridge.

Comment: If I could upvote twice, I would add another for your description of the build system:)

Comment: I don't suppose [`_POSIX_C_SOURCE`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/xsh_chap02_02.html) for [feature-enablement](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html) of that which you desire has been properly defined?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Unfortunately we're at sea level and the tide is in. Plus I refuse to be beaten by those damn Elbonians.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally got the hateful thing to build, unfortunately more through brute force & ignorance than some elegant master-stroke of coding genius.

However, should it help some future generation, the route I followed was this:

- Add `-lrt -lpthread` to `C_FLAGS` in my example makefile, and then tried to `make`
- When `make` failed, look at the location where it failed, load the makefile from that place and add `-lrt -lpthread` in a similar fashion in that makefile.
- Lather, rinse, repeat until `make` succeeds.

**It now seems to work OK**, of course there are now 100 other bugs to fix, but at least I got it to compile in the end.

*Nurse, the screens!*

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you mean by the first question.  I will attempt to cover all possibilities.

The answer to the second question was pretty much covered by Joachim.

Your system *will* attempt to build `messaging.o` if you change `messaging.c`, for example, if you add a header file to the top.

If you want to know, how to succeed that attempt, well, you need to provide the proper location of the file `semaphore.h` in the `INCLUDES` variable.  It is a "system" file, in one of the "system" include directories.

If you want to ensure, that you rebuild `messaging.o` when `semaphore.h` changed, you would need to read the section on advanced auto-dependency generation in the GNU Make Manual or on MadScientist's site http://mad-scientist.net/make/autodep.html

Or, use the ElectricAccelerator, that EricMelski talks about all the time.  That fantastic software, has automatic dependency generation built-in for free.  You don't have to do a thing.

Also, as you already know, the Makefile you are showing is very poorly written, very "naiive".  And it sounds like you have a recursive system of several thousand of similarly poor Makefiles.  Yes, it is terrible.

And it sounds like you personally do not want to fix this build system as such, you are just interested to add some functionality to the software itself.

So, I think you need to hire an expert consultant to write your company a state-of-the-art system, perhaps using ElectricAccelerator, or plain old GNU Make.  Do you get the hint? Ehm, , if Eric can put plugs here all the time and he gets away with it, then so can I :)

Comment: I personally would **love** to fix this whole system, but a one-man ground-up rewrite of an SDK containing millions of lines of code is not something the customer is going to pay me to spend the next 10 years doing.

Comment: No I was just talking about rewriting the build system, the Makefiles.  No, it would not be 10 years.  All build projects take 1/2 year or less, regardless of the size.  That is "Mark's law" :)    Sounds like you are a consultant yourself, working for that client company, but you are not interested in fixing the build system, you just want to add functionality to the SDK itself.

Comment: I'd settle for gaining a better understanding of WTF is going on & how I make it build reliably. If our customer could afford superstar expert consultants he wouldn't be paying us to do the work of 10 people in half the time for 1/50th the cash... of course that means we can't afford superstar expert consultants either - not until we get this junk working and sell a few thousand units at least!